# Using MSXML 2.0 to perform XSLT Transformation

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, dom

I am trying some ways to perform the xslt transformation using xslt and xml as string.
If we pass the url of the xml file then it works fine using load() method.

```
function init(xml, xslt) {
    var srcTree = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
    srcTree.async=false;
    srcTree.load(xml); 
    var xsltTree= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
    xsltTree.async = false;
    xsltTree.load(xslt);
    var resTree = document.getElementById("HTMLData");
    resTree.innerHTML = srcTree.transformNode(xsltTree);
}
```

In the above method we are passing the location (url) of the xml and xslt. But as per requirements, we need to pass the entire xml and xslt as string (like `<?xml version=` ....).
If you find difficult to understand my question then also comment that this question
is not easily understandable. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

the above function can be called using (example):

```
init('/myfiles/xml/books.xml', '/myfiles/xslt/style.xslt');
```

But i need to store the xml as a string variable in javascript and then pass these string
variable to the init method. example:

```
var xmlDocument = '<?xml version='1'?><books>....</books>';
var xsltDocument = '<?xml version='1'?><xsl xmlns:xsl='...'....</xsl>';
init(xmlDocument, xsltDcoument);
```

Comment: You realize that this will only work in IE?! Let's not create IE-only solutions - we aren't in the 1990's anymore.

Comment: Yeah you're absolutely right but client strictly requires it to work ONLY in IE!!!!

Comment: Well, it would be still a good thing if it worked in other browsers.

Comment: **please**, ask the question. what you'd like to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `loadXml` instead than `load` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms754585(v=vs.85).aspx

```
function init(xml, xslt) { 
    var srcTree = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0"); 
    srcTree.async=false; 
    srcTree.loadXml(xml);  
    var xsltTree= new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0"); 
    xsltTree.async = false; 
    xsltTree.loadXml(xslt); 
    var resTree = document.getElementById("HTMLData"); 
    resTree.innerHTML = srcTree.transformNode(xsltTree); 
}
```